# ORM for Javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, sql, json, orm

I am working on a web application that gets JSON data from the server (Ruby/Rails) into the client using jQuery/ajax and then renders it to the browser using jQuery to populate the DOM. To simplify access to my data on the client side, I would like to use an object-relational mapper similar to ActiveRecord, but which starts with JSON data instead of data directly from a SQL data source.

Are there any such ORMs in Javascript that convert a JSON data set (itself derived from a set of SQL queries on the server side) to a set of ActiveRecord-like objects?

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something here, but JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is already a Javascript object in and of itself.

If the data you are getting from the server doesn't map well to a usable Javascript object, I would argue that it's the server side that needs to change to return a more useful serialized object rather than a simple recordset.

Comment: This answer is kind of out of date, since JavaScript now has classes and class syntax that can be used together with TypeScript or Flow for better type-checking.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS has a very nice JsonStore class

Comment: Yes, ExtJS does that but in my opinion, I find it hindered by massive amounts of legacy code and a bad personality.

Comment: I see. Didn't have a lot to do with them folks.

Answer (score 0):

There is [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB) which is a DB written in Erlang that uses HTTP as the transport. This eliminates the need for middle-ware and permits you to navigate the DB directly with AJAX calls. I can't speak good or bad about it. I haven't heard much about it in months and it seems as if the hype train departed a few years ago.

You can't have an ORM to a remote DB in Javascript.. An, ORM requires transcendental knowledge of the DB schema, and sending that out with an API just isn't that pragmatic as of yet.

For persistent local storage, there is the now deprecated Google Gears and the HTML5 Clientside DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is [JSON ODM](https://github.com/konsultaner/jsonOdm). Exactly what you are looking for. If you need a method that is not supported yet post an issue and I'll try my best to support it as soon as possible.

If you like it please give it a star!